# Are expression trees thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I want to cache some expressions that are generated dynamically (with LinqKit) in order to pass them to a `Where` clause that is part of an Entity Framework query.

So I have something like

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> _expression; // Gets a value at runtime

public IQueryable<T> Apply(IQueryable<T> query) 
{        
    return query.Where(_expression); // Here _expression already has a value
}
```

Is it safe for multiple threads to call `Apply` and then execute those queries in parallel? Is the `Expression<TDelegate>` class thread-safe?

Docs only give the standard "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe..."

Comment: A good doc to read [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/)

Comment: Seems too philosophical to me. I simply want to know if two parallel queries work when they have the same predicate expression object in their Where part.

Comment: AFAIK, expression trees are immutable, and therefore are thread safe.

Comment: OK, the the answer is *Maybe*, depending on how you use it... It is, for ex, possible to read and process the same items twice...

Comment: Are you changing `_expression`? The expression tree itself is immutable and therefore should be thread-safe but the field is mutable. So it depends on how you modify the field.

Comment: No, I don't change anything. My question is whether Expression itself is threadsafe, not what will happen when I assign _expression and at the same time other stuff is happening.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Expression trees themselves are immutable. However, they can refer to things that *do* change, e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int multiplier = 3;
        IQueryable<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2 }.AsQueryable();
        Expression<Func<int, int>> expression = x => x * multiplier;

        // Prints 3, 6
        foreach (var item in values.Select(expression))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        multiplier = 5;

        // Prints 5, 10
        foreach (var item in values.Select(expression))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

If your expression tree only refers to things that don't change, it should be fine. That will be the case in most situations.

If your expression tree *does* refer to mutable state, the if one thread mutates that state, other threads applying the expression tree may or may not see the change, in the normal way of memory models.

Comment: In my case they don't use closures. Only things like t => t.Name == "SomeName". So I guess it's safe.

Comment: @user764754: Yes, that should be fine. It's fine even if does close over variables, so long as they don't change value.